# convert to int php

Tags: php, file-io, twitter, converters

I use php programming for get information from txt file like this:

```
< n >1< /n >< fr >2,3,4,5,6,7,8< /fr >< fo >9,10,11,12< /fo >
```

between tag `< n >`  I can get number 1 by using preg_match

```
$users = preg_match_all("/<".$tag.">[^<]*(.*?)<\/$tag>/si", $content, $matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

so the data is stored in $user[0] right?

when I convert $user[0] to integer, it turns to 0 !!!

Could you please help me fix this

I want to convert this and insert into database

Comment: You are using a regular expression to extract data from XML. Don't do this. Use an XML parser to parse your XML.

Comment: how to use xml parser to parse my xml. could you please tell me more detail. I'm a beginner for php

Comment: For beginners I'd recommend [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml). See the [Examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php) section.

Answer (score 2):

The data is stored in the multi-dimensional array `$matches`. In `$users` will be "the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred." see documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php